# Is $x - \ln \left|\frac{(x+1)^3}{(x-2)^2}\right| + K$ equal to $x + \ln \left|\frac{(x-2)^2}{(x+1)^3}\right| + K $

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus

I solved a problem with solution $$x - \ln \left|\frac{(x+1)^3}{(x-2)^2}\right| + K$$

The answer in my textbook is

$$x + \ln \left|\frac{(x-2)^2}{(x+1)^3}\right| + K $$

I'd like to know how to check whether they're equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are equal. This is because

$$\frac 1{\left| \frac ab \right|}=\left| \frac ba \right|$$

for $a\ne 0,\ b\ne 0$, and

$$\ln\frac 1a=-\ln a$$

for $a>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are equal. Using the property of logarithms, $a\ln(x)=\ln(x^a)$ for $x>0$, we see that 
$$-\ln\left\vert\frac{(x+1)^3}{(x-2)^2}\right\vert=\ln\left\vert\frac{(x-2)^2}{(x+1)^3}\right\vert$$
and so both expressions are the same.